# Link Azure DevOps board with Bitbucket Server (On-Premise)

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket-server

We are using Azure DevOps Board and like to link it with Bitbucket On-premise Server to see commits and pull requests to work board items (cards), and also create feature branches on Bitbucket repo from within Azure DevOps board Items (cards).

I can see the way to link via service connection for Bitbucket Cloud, but can't see how can on-premise bitbucket server be connected?

Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I would checkout this topic => [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66340769/access-a-on-premise-bitbucket-server-from-azure-devops) or this => [Link](https://youtu.be/qq8PudEqhuE)

Comment: Thanks, @KristianKanchev both links are related to Azure DevOps Pipeline, I am looking for Azure DevOps Board.